# 手伝ってくれませんか・手伝えませんか・手伝いましょう

Tags: volitional-form

I recently read that 手伝いましょう is a correct way to offer to help someone. What are the differences between the following sentences? Please explain why any of them are an incorrect.

- 手伝ってくれませんか。
- 手伝えませんか。
- 手伝いませんか。
- 手伝いましょう。

Comment: 手伝ってくれませんか is asking somebody to help you, not offering help ...

Comment: I thought 手伝ってもらえませんか is asking somebody to help you. What does it mean?

Comment: 手伝ってもらえませんか is *also* asking somebody to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are English equivalents. They're not all necessarily word-for-word translations, but they capture the nuances and situational appropriateness, I think.

> 手伝ってくれませんか。
>   Can you please help me?
>
> 手伝えませんか。
>   Won't you be able help me? (See note*)
>
> 手伝いませんか。
>   Will you help me? (See note*)
>
> 手伝いましょう。
>   Let me help you out. (Note: I often hear this as 手伝いましょうか or 手伝おうか)

*Note: I don't hear these often, probably there are more polite ways to say these, like 手伝ってもらえませんか、手伝ってもらっても良いですか、or 敬語 depending on the situation.